# Greyed out questions on main...?

Tags: discussion

Whats the deal with this?  The site is greying out certain posts for me...?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your preferences you have ignored the tag "earth-like", as a result any questions with that tag in them get greyed out.

Assuming you ignored it by accident you can go back into your preferences and de-ignore it.

Comment: No idea how I did that but yeah fixed.  Thanks Tim